# In a plugin, what's the way in PHP to output a CSRF token?

Tags: plugin-development, csrf

My plugin has a tab in the CP. On that tab is a form. What's the way for PHP to generate a CSRF token that can be output to the form with echo?

**EDIT to document the final answer**

```
$token = craft()->request->getCsrfToken();
$out .= <<<MYFORM
   <form action="#" method="post">
      <input type='hidden' name="CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN" value='$token'>
      ...
   </form>
MYFORM;
return $out;
```

And make sure that /craft/config/general.php includes this:

```
return array(
       'enableCsrfProtection' => true,
);
```

Comment: Definitely don't use `echo`. If you want to pass data back to your Twig template, there are several other (much better) ways to do it. Most of the time you'll want to use a Variable defined by your plugin.

Comment: @LindseyD Yes, sorry, I'm doing that, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try `craft()->request->getCsrfToken()`, see if that does it?

**Edit**

Sorry, misunderstood the question, since you are saying your plugin has a CP section then i'm assuming you're actually looking for a twig way to output the CSRF input, not so much a PHP way. To output the CRSF input in your template simply do `{{ getCsrfInput() }}`

Comment: Thank you, that works, in conjunction with `<input type='hidden' name="CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN" value='{craft()->request->getCsrfToken()}'>`